# Error when updating model: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Hi am getting the following exception whenever I try to update my model and save changes using entity framework. And for the life of me, I can't figure out what is causing the exception. This exception is raised in the DataContext Attach method.

Though there similar post about this particular exception here in stackoverflow and in other places, all the ones I have seen focused on when deleting a parent without specifying the Cascade delete on the configuration of the parent-child relationship. But the exception is thrown whenever I try to update this model therefore leaving me perplexed as to the cause of the exception.

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Here is the model

```
public class FreelanceJob : IEntity
{
    //Private members
    private ICollection<Bid> _bids;
    private ICollection<Skill> _skills;

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int PostedById { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile PostedBy { get; set; }

    public int ViewCount { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Specificies a user can apply to (or bid on)  this job
    /// </summary>
    public bool CanApply { get; set; }

    public JobType JobType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This represents the target geographical
    ///     location this job is being targeted at
    /// </summary>
    public JobScope JobScope { get; set; }

    public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }

    public bool IsAwarded { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This is used to identify jobs that has
    ///     not been completed by the job owner,
    ///     and thereby should not be listed as a new job.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsDefinitionCompleted { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public decimal MiniumPrice { get; set; }

    public decimal MaximumPrice { get; set; }

    public bool IsFreelanceCompleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids
    {
        get { return _bids ?? (_bids = new List<Bid>()); }
        protected set { _bids = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills
    {
        get { return _skills ?? (_skills = new List<Skill>()); }
        set { _skills = value; }
    }

}
```

and here is the code first configuration

```
HasKey(a => a.Id);
Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

Property(a => a.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20000);
Property(a => a.Title).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(1000);

Property(a => a.PostedOn).IsRequired();
Property(a => a.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();

HasRequired(a => a.PostedBy).WithMany(a => a.PostedFreelanceJobs).HasForeignKey(a => a.PostedById);
HasRequired(a => a.Category).WithMany(a => a.FreelanceJobs).HasForeignKey(a => a.CategoryId);

Property(a => a.MaximumPrice).IsRequired();
Property(a => a.MiniumPrice).IsRequired();

Property(a => a.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();

HasMany(a => a.Bids)
    .WithRequired(a => a.PlacedOnFreelanceWork)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.PlaceOnFreelanceWorkId);


HasMany(a => a.Skills).WithMany(a => a.FreelanceJobs);
```

Comment: You say you get the error when you're updating the model - what are you updating?

Comment: I get error whenever I modified FreelanceJob entity and try to persist the changes to the database.

Comment: We need to see what you are doing before the error. Otherwise it's guessing which property change can be the cause.

Comment: Here  is the code that is throwing the exception ` job.CanApply = false;
                    job.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;
                    _freelanceService.Update(job);
                    _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();` the exception throws whenever I call `_freelanceService.Update(freelance);`

Comment: The error throws when the ` _dbSet.Attach(entity);` method is called